# Cannot use greater key-length than 8 bits in DESEngine

Tags: java

I'm doing a project where I need to use DESEngine. I'm unable to use a key length of more than 8 bits. Is it possible to use a greater key-length?

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to use DES? It has not been considered secure in the last > 30 years, and even triple-DES is considered unsecure now. Use AES or better if this is not a legacy project. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619212/is-des-or-3des-still-being-used-today

Answer (score 1):

> DES has a block size of 64 bits and a key size of 56 bits

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher